# Gnu AWK split by pattern and insert columns , but get more delimiter

Tags: split, gawk

I have used same `awk` file to process two different string. So wired.

```
cat test.awk
BEGIN{FPAT="([^,])*|(\"[^\"]+\")";OFS=","}{$4="TDP,-1,-1,0,0"OFS$4;print $0}
```

1. `echo "a,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,\"a,b\"" | gawk -f test.awk`

   a,b,b,TDP,-1,-1,0,0,b,,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,"a,b"
2. `echo "a,b,,\"a,b\""|gawk -f test.awk`

   a,b,,TDP,-1,-1,0,0,"a,b"

Actually,for the first one, there is ",," in the result. But I am  expecting the second result in the first one.

Answer (score 0):

*[Not really an answer - but too big for a comment]*

I *think* the behavior you're seeing is *related* to the first atom of your `FPAT` - which potentially has a zero-length match i.e. `([^,])*` matches *zero or more* non-comma characters - but exactly *how* it is related eludes me at this point. Consider for example (GNU Awk 4.0.1):

```
$ echo "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,\"m,n\"" | 
  gawk '
    BEGIN{FPAT="([^,])*|(\"[^\"]+\")";OFS=","}
    {print $0; $4=$4; print $0; print NF}
  '      a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,"m,n"
a,b,c,d,,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,"m,n"
14
```

whereas if we access the value of `NF` before the re-assignement

```
$ echo "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,\"m,n\"" | 
  gawk '
    BEGIN{FPAT="([^,])*|(\"[^\"]+\")";OFS=","}
    {print $0; print NF; $4=$4; print $0; print NF}
  '
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,"m,n"
13
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,"m,n"
13
```

Regardless, the behavior seems to be unambiguous if you change `FPAT` to only match non-empty sequences:

```
$ echo "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,\"m,n\"" | 
  gawk '
    BEGIN{FPAT="([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")";OFS=","}
    {$4="TDP,-1,-1,0,0" OFS $4; print $0}
  '
a,b,c,TDP,-1,-1,0,0,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,"m,n"
```

Comment: thanks steeldrive. Actually, I can't ignore the empty column. I find a workaround for this by using NF-$number.